# How to create a new c++ array from <array> header?

Tags: c++, stl

We can create dinamic C arrays of size determined at runtime (given to constructor). How to create a C++ array of not preditermined size (std::array one)?

Comment: err no, use `std::vector<>`..

Comment: Oh... Complete misunderstand of C++. `std::array` introduced in C++11 and *it is* a fixed-size arrays. Use `std::vector` instead. And you can allocate both on heap and on stack.

Comment: @m0nhawk But is there ever any time you'd want to allocate either dynamically?

Comment: @m0nhawk You're even less clear now.

Comment: I think @m0nhawk is quite clear. He's now also quite wrong. It's generally a bad idea to put `std::array`s on the stack (size-wise), you'd usually want them on the heap, but both are legal.

Answer (score 2):

`std::array` takes the size at compile time via a template parameter. It is pratically impossible to create one with runtime size, and even if you did set up a function table with functions that create `std::array`s of different sizes, you couldn't use them properly.

Really, you should use `std::vector` for runtime size.

You also might want to have a look at [`boost::container::static_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html), a container with stack-memory and fixed capacity but dynamic size.